Code with Only One State Update Is Re-rendered Twice in React
I am learning from the React Docs. A piece of code confuses me a lot. When I click the "Posts (slow)" button, the PostsTab.js run twice, according to the log that appears twice. I think it should only run once because of the "tab" state update. I have no idea why it runs twice.

StrictMode will run your app twice.

In development, React intentionally renders components twice to check for unexpected behaviour. It happens only in StrictMode and doesn't impact production performance. In production, components will be rendered once.
• Check if you're using Strict Mode (look for <React.StrictMode> in your main app file).
• Try building for production - you should see normal behaviour there.
Reference: Why is my React component is rendering twice?

Thank you for answering, but I do not use , which I checked before.

In the example that you provide, <StrictMode> is in index.js which was not displayed in react dev page, see the source code by click Fork.
